# Button Text Alignment in Outlook.com

Tags: html, css, html-email

Finding a strange behavior only in outlook.com with a button text alignment for an email build. For some reason it's aligned to the top of the button instead of being in the middle. Unable to figure out why this is. Any insights appreciated.

Thank you for your time and thoughts.

Code snippet and CTA image link below.

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"  >
     <tr>
      <td style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;  background-color:#989b98; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#e4008f; cursor: pointer; display: block; min-height: 45px; vertical-align: middle; min-width: 220px;" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; padding: 12px 20px 10px 20px;  background-color:#989b98; color:#e4008f; cursor: pointer; display: block; border: 1px solid #989b98; min-width: 220px; font-weight: bold;  outline: none;" target="_blank">16pxXXXX XXXXX XXXXX</a></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

[image: Screen grab of CTA text alignment in Outlook.com]

Answer (score 1):

I would first start off by reviewing [**this asset**](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for anything "email" related in order to get an understanding of how different email clients react with CSS.

You will notice how `display` is not supported in Outlook which would result in your anchor tag not being able to use padding. I would recommend coding an email button the following way:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#989b98" style="padding: 12px 20px; font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">
            <a href="#" style="color: #e4008f; text-decoration: none; outline: none; border: none;" target="_blank">16pxXXXX XXXXX XXXXX</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This unfortunately only makes the text clickable and not the entire button, but it's going to be your best option in order to make it consistent across all other email clients without having to create an image.

Comment: Thank you mdurchholz for your reply. I just realized I have a placeholder in the href="#". Once I put a url in, the text aligned in the middle of the CTA in Outlook.com.